# Add Unique to 3 columns at the same time

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-socialite

i'm having a table called `social_accounts` to store the data for OAuth Login

```
id
user_id
provider
provider_id
```

I want to make `user_id,provider,provider_id` UNIQUE but i want all 3 columns be unique at the same time 
meaning a user with id `x` can have a provider_id `b` and provier `google` for example but this row didn't duplicate but the use `x` can have another row with provider `faceook` as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `provider` seems to be redundant here. You should have a separate table with `provider_id` and `provider`

To set a `UNIQUE` index on multiple columns try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `social_accounts` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`user_id`, `provider_id`);
```

However if you want to stick to your approach having `provider` in the table so use this one:

```
ALTER TABLE `social_accounts` 
ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`user_id`, `provider_id`, `provider`);
```

Also note that `unique_index` is the name of your index and can be name how ever you want.